# Pass variable to Formvalidation.io ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I am using the formvalidtion.io plugin for AJAX form submit and validation,
I am passing `selector` argument to the function, and I want to access that selector in final AJAX success,

```js
var _StoreItem = function(selector) {
  FormValidation.formValidation(
    document.getElementById('demoForm'), {
      fields: {
        // ...
      },
      plugins: {
        // ...
      },
    }
  ).on('core.form.valid', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/tourl/xyz',
      data: $("#demoForm").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.val == 1) {
          //Access selector here
          selector.find('.rate').first().val(data.price).trigger("change");
          selector.find('.desc').first().val(data.desc);
        }
      },
    });
  });
};
```

How can I send an argument to AJAX success?

Comment: `selector` is in scope of the `success` handler function so your code will work as it is. Do you have a specific issue with it? Is `selector` a jQuery object, or a string as its name implies? If the latter, that's the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, this is selector, ``` var selector = $(this).closest('tr');```, i am storing clicked items in selector and that is passed to another function sucess, to modify dom values.